# What is the difference between crypt in unistd.h and crypt.h?

Tags: compilation, c, posix, crypt

## Background

`crypt` has two definitions, [from the docs,](https://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt)

1. One of them uses `unistd.h`

   ```
   #define _XOPEN_SOURCE       /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
   #include <unistd.h>
   ```

   This is defined as

   ```
   #ifdef __USE_MISC

   extern char *crypt (const char *__key, const char *__salt)
        __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
   #endif
   ```
2. One of them uses GNU `crypt.h`

   ```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
   #include <crypt.h>
   ```

   This is defined as

   ```
   extern char *crypt (const char *__phrase, const char *__salt)                                                                                          
     __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
   ```

## Problem

When I compile with the definition in the first example (`unistd.h`)

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                                                  
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                   

int main()                                                                                                                                           
{                                                                                                                                                    
  printf("%s", crypt("foobar", "sa"));                                                                                                               
}
```

I'm getting the error

```
In function ‘main’:
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘crypt’; did you mean ‘chroot’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("%s", crypt("foobar", "sa"));
               ^~~~~
               chroot
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%s", crypt("foobar", "sa"));
          ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          %d
```

Out of desperation, I've tried adding this.

```
#define _XOPEN_VERSION 700
#define _POSIX_VERSION 200809L
#define __USE_MISC 1
```

On Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 I believe this works fine use the `unistd.h` declaration, which makes all the more confusing.

Comment: This is a question about C, not about Linux usage or administration.

Answer (score 3):

These are two *declarations*, not two *definitions*. The content of the header file has no impact on which definition of a function is included: this is determined by the linker. There is only one definition of the `crypt` function in the Unix C standard library, it's whatever the symbol `crypt` points to in `libcrypt.a` or `libcrypt.so` (depending on whether you link statically or dynamically).

Since the two declarations are compatible, it doesn't matter which header a program gets its through. It's also fine if both declarations are processed: a program can contain any number of declarations for a function as long as they're compatible. Without going into the exact details (refer to the C language specification), two function declarations are compatible if they have the same return type, the same number of arguments and the same type for each argument. The name of the argument given in a declaration is not significant.

Comment: That's what I would think but I know some of this stuff is defined internally and does some deep voodoo (at least with c99.h magic). If they are the same definitions, why would the [`unistd.h` version not work then (my other question)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/498069/3285)

Comment: The `crypt` function is not defined internally. It's defined in a library, not one of those functions for which the compiler itself can generate code. The deep voodoo is for conditional inclusion of the _declaration_, not the definition. The two headers that declare this function do so with different preprocessor guard. What preprocessor symbols to define to get the declaration from `unistd.h` is your other question.

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore `unistd.h`. That declaration is there for POSIX compatibility but GLIB has removed the definition for `crypt` when they migrated to `libxcrypt` to develop those features in isolation of glibc. This means you can still get ABI-compatibility but must link in the `crypt`. You can read more about that [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1566464)

> Availability in glibc
>
> The `crypt ()`, `encrypt ()`, and `setkey ()` functions are part of the POSIX.1-2008 XSI Options Group for Encryption and are optional. If the interfaces are not available then the symbolic constant `_XOPEN_CRYPT` is either not defined or defined to -1, and can be checked at runtime with `sysconf ()`.
>
> This may be the case if the downstream distribution has switched from glibc crypt to `libxcrypt`.  When recompiling applications in such distributions the
>    user must detect if `_XOPEN_CRPYT` is not available and include crypt.h for the function prototypes; otherwise `libxcrypt` is a ABI compatible drop-in replacement.

As for why even if you link the definition isn't pulled down with

```
#define _XOPEN_VERSION 700
#define _POSIX_VERSION 200809L
#define __USE_MISC 1
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

Well there are a few things that happening there

1. The only header that matters in `unistd.h` is `__USE_MISC`.
2. `unistd.h` includes `features.h` which [`undef`s the `__USE_` macros to start with a "clean slate"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/498176/3285)
3. The only way to define `__USE_MISC` is to have defined `_GNU_SOURCE`.

If you want to pull in the declaration of `crypt.h` from `unistd.h` you must define `_GNU_SOURCE`! **Those two examples cited from [man page of `crypt.h`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) do the same thing and whether you include `unistd.h` or `crypt.h` you MUST also define `_GNU_SOURCE`** in contemporary versions of glibc.

So you can either do,

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```

Or,

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>
```

But because you must link against `crypt` (`-lcrypt`) I would suggest using the declaration in `crypt.h` for sanity.